# SharePoint pop-up message when using the ribbon, all in IE9

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

If I try to modify a public-facing page, from the SharePoint ribbon, in IE, I get a pop-up message that says "This page is accessing information that is not under its control.  This poses a security risk. Do you want to continue"  How come this only happens in IE and what would be some general steps to help debug this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had external Google CSS links in head of my Master Template, and IE care's much to prompt me on that..problem found and fixed by removing the links.